# best storage options for photostocks

Tags: firebase, web, storage, firebase-storage

I'm developing a social network (website) with options to upload albums with high-res photos and videos. the users will be professional photographers who will upload albums between 120-150 high res photos and videos.

what are the best options for me to use in order to store those files?
I'm using firebase as my database and static content storage, so I thought it would be great to use firebase storage. but there are limitations of 1000GB of storage and I'm not sure this will be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"but there are limitations of 1000GB of storage and I'm not sure this will be enough." Where are you seeing this limit?

Cloud Storage for Firebase shares it's infrastructure with Google Cloud Storage (they're the same product with different SDK surfaces), which is used by the worlds largest tech companies for file storage. Each object can be up to 5TB in size, which is 5x the "limit" mentioned above.

Comment: yea I was not sure if it is the same as GCS. thanks!